# what to do when two elements have same resource id in appium?

Tags: appium

what to do when the resource-id of two elements in list view in UIAutomator of appium is same??

here in the images below:-

both the elements have same resource id:-net.one97.paytm:id/smart_list_root

[image: Figure 1]
[image: Figure 1]

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you can use xpath or name like below:

**Way 1:**

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.TextView[@text='Mobile Prepaid']"));
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.TextView[@text='Mobile Postpaid']"));
```

**Way 2:**

```
driver.findElement(By.name("Mobile Prepaid"));
driver.findElement(By.name("Mobile Postpaid"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the text using xpath:

`String text = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.RelativeLayout")).getText();`

Compare the text and select the correct UIElement to perform desired action.

`if(text.equals("Mobile Prepaid")){
   ......
}`

Comment: method is correct but it is not clicking on that element

Answer (score 0):

Take it with multiple elements for xpath for textview as

```
"//android.widget.TextView[@text='Mobile Prepaid']"
```

Hope it will work

Answer (score 0):

You can use `By.name` like,

```
driver.findElement(By.name("Mobile Prepaid"));
driver.findElement(By.name("Mobile Postpaid"));
```

Comment: With Appium 1.5 name selector was removed. If you are using 1.5 , go with driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.TextView[@text='Mobile Prepaid']"))

Answer (score 0):

```
String ac = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//*[@resource-id = 'account-balance-amount'])[1]")).getText();

String ac = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//*[@resource-id = 'account-balance-amount'])[2]")).getText();
```